# How can I prevent the button from triggering the other button when I click it? &React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My problem is when I click my watched button, it also triggers handler button. How can I prevent that?

Here is my buttons code:
HTML:

```
<div className="bot">
                <button id="handler" onClick={() =>{handleClick(0)}}>PICK IT</button>

                <button id="watched" onClick={() =>{watched()}}>I Already Watched This</button>

                <a href={data.trailer} target = "_blank" className = "button">WATCH TRAILER</a>
               

            </div>
```

React & Firebase part:

```
function watched(){
        const db = getDatabase(app);
        update(ref(db,"users/" + userInfo + "/watched/" + data.id),{"watched" : "true"});
    } 

    function handleClick(val){
        if (val >= 250){return 1;}
        const numberOfUsers = 250;
        const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfUsers);
        const database = getDatabase(app);
        const watched = ref(database,"users/" + userInfo + "/watched/" + randomIndex);
        onValue(watched,(snapshot) =>{
            if (snapshot.val().watched === "true"){
                handleClick(val+1)
            }
            else{
                const starCountRef = ref(database, 'movies/');
                onValue(starCountRef, (snapshot) => {
                const data = snapshot.val();
                setData(data[randomIndex])
            });}
        })
```

Comment: The two buttons appear to be completely isolated. Nothing shown would indicate why you get those symptoms. How do you know clicking one triggers click on the other? Can you put together a demo that displays this behavior?

Comment: @charlietfl as you can see when I click handler button it set some data (useState), after that my page rendered due to that data. But when I click watched button, it also set some data and my page renders another movie. But I didn't set any data on watched button.

Comment: Are these buttons inside a form?

Comment: @charlietfl no they are not

Comment: That behavior is very strange. Nither button should be aware of events on the other. Try to put a demo together that reproduces it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem like this:

```
function handleClick(val){
        console.log("handlerrr");
        if (val >= 250){return 1;}
        const numberOfUsers = 250;
        const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfUsers);
        const database = getDatabase(app);
        const watched = ref(database,"users/" + userInfo + "/watched/" + randomIndex);
        onValue(watched,(snapshot) =>{
            const val = snapshot.val()  <-------- THIS LINE ADDED
            if (val === "true"){
                handleClick(val+1)
            }
            else{
                const starCountRef = ref(database, 'movies/');
                onValue(starCountRef, (snapshot) => {
                const data = snapshot.val();
                setData(data[randomIndex])
            });}
        })
```

I am not sure but probably problem was when onValue worked after that my handleClick function was listening my database and after each update on my database it was triggering. So I added const val = snapshot.val() now it is only rendering 1 time.

Answer (score 0):

Just add event inside onClick function  `onClick={(e) =>{handleClick(e, 0)}`. Adding this event you will prevent triggering button without actual click.